# Include tagged commit in "git fetch --shallow-exclude mytag"

Tags: git

I want to fetch all commits from remote up to a certain tagged commit.

The option `--shallow-exclude` looks promising, but it also excludes the tagged commit.

The following command would fetch all commits from remote excluding the tagged commit and all parent commits.

```
git fetch --shallow-exclude v1.0.0
```

Is it somehow possible to also fetch the commit tagged by `v1.0.0`?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a better option than to use `git fetch --deepen=1` after `git fetch --shallow-exclude mytag`.

Comment: You need `--deepen=2` because v1.0.0's direct child was also excluded.